# Boolean - Does ID Exist in Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables... A master ID table and a results ID table with only a few IDs from the master table. I'm looking to create the following SQL Query:

```
Select
   A.ID
   (Case when B.ID is in A.ID 1 Else 0 End) as is_found
From
   master_table as A
   LEFT JOIN results_table as B
   ON A.ID = B.ID
```

The resulting table should have all IDs from master table with a boolean column saying if the ID was found in the results table. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Which are you using, MySQL or SQL-Server?

Comment: SQL-Server. Oops. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `case . . . exists`:

```
Select mt.id,
       (case when exists (select 1 from results_table rt where rt.id = mt.id) then 1 else 0 end) as is_found
From master_table ;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, consider the case where `results_table` will have either zero or one matching row; in this case, the `LEFT JOIN` will always give one row for each ID, and `B.ID` will be `NULL` if there is no corresponding row in `results_table`.

We can therefore use a simple `CASE` to test this:

```
Select
   A.ID,
   CASE WHEN B.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as is_found
From
   master_table as A
   LEFT JOIN results_table as B
   ON A.ID = B.ID
```

If there may be *more than one* row in `results_table` for the same ID, the `LEFT JOIN` may in turn create several rows, one for each match.

The result of the `CASE` statement will be the same for all values of `A.ID` - if there are zero matches, it will occur once with value `0`, and if there are one or more, it will always have the value `1`. So we can simply take distinct values of the entire query:

```
Select Distinct
   A.ID,
   CASE WHEN B.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as is_found
From
   master_table as A
   LEFT JOIN results_table as B
   ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: Since `A.ID = B.ID`, there's no need to group by both of them.

Comment: @Barmar That depends whether the DBMS correctly recognises that fact. The safe / portable option is to always group by or aggregate all columns you select.

Comment: You're not selecting B.ID.

Comment: I guess it should be `GROUP BY A.ID, is_found`. Or just `SELECT DISTINCT ...`

Comment: @Barmar That's true; I was still making assumptions about what the DBMS would recognise as "dependent". `SELECT DISTINCT` is probably the way to go, here.